# Licença do Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, aplicação-web

Ola, estou tentado embarcar ao mundo dos aplicativos multiplataforma, e após algum tempo de pesquisa realizei alguns testes e li sobre o assunto, cheguei a duas plataformas a Intel XDK e o Phonegap(o da intel acabou por apresentar algumas lentidões) e agora estou focando o segundo, porém cheguei a uma dúvida, a licença free dele me obriga a postar o meu source no github caso eu exceda o limite de uma app privada? ou ele me obriga a postar minha app gratuitamente, mas mantendo o source privado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na versão free você pode ter apenas um app privado, caso o limite atinja você é obrigado a deixar o código free no github.

Segue a tabela no link: https://build.phonegap.com/

Ele vai apenas compilar seu código, então depois que compila você faz o que quiser com o app. Inclusive pode deixa-lo pago.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara. Uma noticia chata, mas 10 dólares mensais não é tão salgado.